# Having Issues installing tabulizer package in R

Tags: r, pdf, rjava, tabulizer

I had a script working with tabulizer, but had to clean my hard drive and reinstall R, and now I cant seem to even download and access the tabulizer library. I am now using R version 4.1.2 64 bit, and am thinking maybe I need to use an earlier version of R??? Here is the error message I get when I try and install tabulizer.

```
install.packages("tabulizer")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cdonner/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tabulizer’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I have tried to go to go to Cran (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tabulizer/) and download and unzip the libraries to my directory, but then I get an errors again. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try GitHub version https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer

Comment: @Tung - Using the below line of code which was in the readme file in the github repo made it work!:

remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Enter this into the command window!

```
remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi I also have this problem but this solution is not working for me. I am also using 4.1.2 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not on CRAN.
You have to install using

```
ghit::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer")
```

or

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/tabulizer")
```

[github](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/44)

Answer (score 2):

I have just come to dealing with the same problem, but I got to solve it through the following steps:

1. the `tabulizer` package requires a Java environment. You need to [download](https://www.java.com/en/download/) Java 64-bit or Java 32-bit through.
   Make sure before that your windows/ mac is 32 bit or 64 bit by using the function sessionInfo().
2. Install the `rJava` package in R.
3. Create the Java environment through the command: `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-18/")`

Attention: the path of the file in step 3 is for java 64. the path for java 32 would be  `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk-18/")`.
The other thing is that jdk-18 changes depending on everylaptop, in my case it is jdk-18, in your case it could jdk-17 for example.

4. Finally activate the library: `library(rJava)`
5. Voila. `rJava` and `tabulizer` work smoothly and nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. (A lot) Packages were missing

- I had to update R
- Install java for R
- Install Rtools42 from CRan
- Install remotes

before running the command of @Dunbar111

```
remotes::install_github(c("ropensci/tabulizerjars", "ropensci/tabulizer"), INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```